# OpenGL doesn't render on Droid / Milestone

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, I'm writing a game engine.

I have a little example (see http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=http://rokonandroid.com/rd.apk), that seems to work fine on every device except Droid / Milestone.

It displays a blue screen (due to glClearColor being set to blue), and nothing more.

I have tried with/without textures, and with/without VBOs. Yet still all blue screens on Droid.

What is unique about Droid and how it handles OpenGL, and why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using OpenGL ES 2.x perchance?  The droid can't support it.  Alas there is precious little we can do but guess without seeing some source code!

Comment: No, I'm not.

My code is pretty deep, so it wasn't really appropriate to post anything here ...

The engines at
http://code.google.com/p/rokon/source/browse/#svn/trunk

The example in question is at
http://code.google.com/p/rokon/source/browse/#svn/examples/donate_app


But I doubt you want to read through all that ...



Is not supporting OpenGL ES 2.x the only different Droid has?

Comment: AFAIK thats the main difference.  What version of Android is it running?  You are targetting the right version?  Alas I've only really done work with the NDK rather than doingmuch work in Java ... so I'm probably not going to be much help :(